# How to select multiple columns and filter duplicate values in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to select multiple columns and avoid duplicate values in these columns with Laravel.
Here is my data:

```
id, name, job, department
[1, "Jane Doe", "worker", "departmentA"]
[2, "Adam Smith", "manager", "departmentB"]
[3, "Machiavelli", "worker", "departmentA"]
[4, "Rousseau", "worker", "departmentC"]
```

I want to get job and department without duplicate data. So I want this result:

```
[["worker", "manager"], ["departmentA", "departmentB", "departmentC"]]
```

I'm trying to get it with model like that:

```
$users = Users::all();
$user_fields = $users->pluck("job", "department")->toArray();
return $user_fields;
```

But it's not working. How can I do it?

Comment: What is "not working"? An error? not the expected result? You cant expect "pluck" to create an array per column...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think you can do it with one function.

But with two plucks it is simple:

```
$user_fields = 
    [
        $users->pluck("job")->unique()->values()->toArray(),
        $users->pluck("department")->unique()->values()->toArray()
    ];
```

Comment: This is the closest answer. Please update your answer with adding `values()` after the `unique()` and do not merge arrays, just wrap them with array bracket. That was what I want. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you pluck 2 values, you're creating an associative array.

You can split them into separate arrays using `array_keys` and `array_values`. I would use `array_unique` to remove duplicates.

```php
$users = Users::all();

$jobs_despartments = $users->pluck("job", "department")->all();

$jobs = array_unique(array_keys($jobs_despartments));
// ["worker", "manager"]

$departments = array_unique(array_values($jobs_despartments));
// ["departmentA", "departmentB", "departmentC"]
```